# AngularJS Filter without making new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects, each containing sub objects. This array is used in an ng-repeat to print a table of data. An example is as follows:

```
    device {
       "name": "computer"
       ip_addresses {
           "address" : "127.0.0.1",
           "network" : "internet"
       }
       components {
          "type" : "network interface",
          "serial" : "12345"
       }
    }
```

I have created a filter that flattens the object out into a string and searches the entire string for the query entered (allowing you to search not just the outer object but the inner as well).

The filter works, but I keep getting digest errors. I have tried two methods so far, the first is to splice the objects I want to remove out of the array, which causes the filter to take effect permanently, which is not desired (once an object is filtered out, it's permanently removed).

```
    return function (input, filterStr) {
            for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                if (JSON.stringify(input[i]).toUpperCase().indexOf(filterStr.toUpperCase()) == -1)
                {
                    input.splice(i, 1);
                }           
            }

            return input;
        }
```

The other method I have tried is to create a new array and add matching elements to the new array. Because this creates a new array, AngularJS recognizes the objects in the output array as different than objects in the input array, it marks them again, generating a digest error.

```
    return function( items, filterStr) {
            var filtered = [];
            angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
                if (JSON.stringify(item).toUpperCase().indexOf(filterStr.toUpperCase()) != -1)
                {
                    filtered.push(item);
                }           
            });
            return filtered;
        };
```

So my question is: how do I create a filtered output array without modifying the original array and without creating a new array (I.E. how do I generate a filtered array without the risk of digest errors)?

Comment: you can [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) filter function, so for same arguments not eval function again, but return memoize value. For example: http://www.terrencewatson.com/2014/06/28/memoize/

Answer (score 0):

i hope to help, you can try this:

```
function(items, filterStr) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        items.push(filtered: item);
    });
}
```